# How can I determine which version of ESX I have running?

Tags: vmware-esx

I don't mean the build version, I mean whether I have Essentials, Essentials Plus, Standard, Advanced, Enterprise, or Enterprise Plus? Is there somewhere I can look to see this without having to determine it by what features I do have and which I do not?

The sys admin before me purchased this setup and there is no documentation for it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the vSphere Client to connect to the ESX Server.

Click on the CONFIGURATION Tab

Click on  Licensed Features under the Software section.

That should give you all the information you are licensed for for that server.

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Thank you very much for your help.